# Why Angular2 component don`t render template, but rendering path to template?

Tags: angular, frontend, web-frontend

I have an Angular version 2 my components is working without errors but now him don`t render template, early it is working

My component

```
import template from "./edit.html";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "adminOffersEdit",
  template,
})
```

I don't changed code, Angular2 render path to template
[image]

How i can fix this ?

I try recompiling all components, its`not work

I try add `templateUrl: "./edit.html" and i get result [image]

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `templateUrl` directly in your component. There's no need to import it:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "adminOffersEdit",
  templateUrl: "./edit.html",
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't read all html by default, you have to mention html path inside templateUrl. In your case the code should be..

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "adminOffersEdit",
  templateUrl: "./edit.html"
})
```

Now with that angular knows where your html code is, hopefully this should work.

Comment: I add templateUrl in component and now i see in adminoffersedit the html all page